# Android 2.3.3, Eclipse - unable to use button after switching to other layout pages

Tags: android, eclipse, button

Overview:
I have two pages in my program; the main page and the other page.

On the main page I have two buttons; one button switches to the other page and the Add button adds some values together.

On the other page I have a single button that brings me back to the main page.

Currently I'm able to switch between the two pages without issue.

My Issue:
When I first open the program I can click the Add button and it will add the values together. I can continue to change between the two pages without issue.
However, after I have switched pages, when I click the Add button, my program crashes.

Here is my java file.

```
    package com.test;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.*;

    public class AswitchActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button enterScoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    enterScoreButton.setOnClickListener(enterScoreButtonListener);
}

public OnClickListener enterScoreButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v1) 
    {
    }

    public int addEntireHole(int addedHoles) {
        return (addedHoles);
    }
};

//This section goes from the main page to the other page
public OnClickListener Startpage = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v2){
    }
};

public void onCreate(View view){
    Button buttonSwitchMain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);
    buttonSwitchMain.setOnClickListener(Startpage);
    setContentView(R.layout.other);
 }

//This section goes from the other page to the main page

public OnClickListener otherpage = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v3){
    }
};


public void onCreate3(View view2){
    Button buttontoMain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    buttontoMain.setOnClickListener(otherpage);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method `onCreate3`, after calling `setContentView` you should call

```
enterScoreButton.setOnClickListener(enterScoreButtonListener);
```

once again.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestion.  I tried your suggestions and enterScoreButton appears to be out of scope.  So then I added  Button enterScoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) before it and it let me compile and run and it didn't through any errors, but it also didn't seem to execute any code after pressing the Enter button...

Comment: Well, that's something I was wondering about before. When you click the button, the method onClick of the listener is invoked - but yours doesn't contain any code. Please try adding the line Log.v("","CLICKED"); and see whether LogCat shows the message when you click the button.

Comment: The example above is simplified version of my main program; I tried to strip it down to only the bare essentials. I did not know before about using Log.v, but found it really useful. When I put Log.v in the onClick it did show in the LogCat. I tried then copied it Log.v to the addEntireHole part of the code and it never got executed. I was under the impression (probably wrongly) that since the code was part of the enterScoreButtonListener that everything inside of it would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use intents to switch pages, to solve this problem.

Comment: Since I'm just learning, what is the advantage in using intents to switch pages?